# Outlook-VBA: detecting opening a file event

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010, inspector

Using either:

```
Private Sub myInspector_NewInspectr(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
```

or

`Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)`

I need to find out if `Inspector.CurrentItem` or the `Item` loaded are opened from inside of outlook (by clicking an email) or by openning a .msg or .oft file saved somewhere.

I also need to find out the name of the file and the path to it.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that. More than that, recent (Outlook 2007 and newer) versions first create a temporary message in the primary store first when you double click on an MSG file.,

Comment: That's disappointing! Is there a way to intercept the temporary message creation?

Comment: Only when the message is saved... And then there is no way to distinguish it fro ma regular message created by the user and placed in the Drafts folder.